# Is there a way to hide WordPress behind a web visible directory?

Tags: links, security, directory

Is there a way to hide WordPress behind a web visible directory for extra security using a symlink?

Comment: Frontend, admin, or both?

Comment: Using symlinks? Not really. Using a custom web server configuration might work.

Answer (score 1):

Symlink will not give you extra security. Since a symlink just links to the directory you want. So if you want to move wp-admin then there will not be much security there since when a users visit's wp-admin it will still load the files.